# URL redirect to open camera app on iphone

Tags: ios, camera

My scenario is self-checkin at an event.  User has a QR code.

1. There is an iPad on the welcome desk with camera app active.
2. User displays their QR code to it, clicks link, goes to webpage saying "thanks for checking in!"
3. 10 seconds later, Url redirect in iPad switches active app back to camera.

My question is how do I do #3?

If I were building my own app, I see I need to make [universal links](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016308-CH12-SW1):

But all I want to do is redirect to an installed iOS app.  Apple provides the schema camera:// to open the camera.  However, using this URI in the browser seems to be trying to open the web page in the camera app, which fails.  I just want to switch tasks to the camera.

Comment: Have you found any solution? Would also be interested how to open the build-in camera app from an webapp via link.